# Binding of @SpringBootApplication to @RestController in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm implementing a REST API in Kotlin, using two tutorials ([1](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), [2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/spring-boot-restful.html)).

The first one doesn't even include a `main` function to be the app's entry point.
The second, however, does include the following file, which isn't connected in any way (at least not one that I see) to the controller.

```
// ClientApiApplication.kt

@SpringBootApplication
class ClientApiApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ClientApiApplication>(*args)
}
```

And this is the controller I'm using:

```
// GreetingController.kt

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    fun greeting() {
        return "Hello World"
    }

}
```

However, when I run `ClientApiApplication` it *does* recognise the controller.
So where is this binding taking place? Is this something that Spring does out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Under the hood, `@SpringBootApplication` is a composition of the `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations. With this default setting, Spring Boot will auto scan for components in the current package (containing the `@SpringBoot` main class) and its sub packages
> ([source](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-component-scan))

After some more research, apparently this is explained in multiple websites. It's a shame the basic tutorials don't refer to it as well *shrug*